# What should I do? let this product branch in two, or keep it unified

Tags: project-management

I am a first time intern at a large corporation and I created a GUI tool that lets my coworkers visualize the log file that their product produces. The tool, known as MRI, is nearing completion and I face a conflict.

One party, (Two ambitious Indian guys that live in California) want me to adapt MRI to a new format and to display much more detailed information. The current version of MRI is built around the idiosyncrasies of the 20 year old log file format. In my opinion it is a bad idea to attempt to grow a more powerful, more universal tool out of a less powerful and idiosyncratic one (Better to start from scratch; something I probably don't have time to do).

The other party is composed of several marketing types and my father. They are drooling over the shiny new GUI that I slapped on top of their crazy old log file, and every one of them wants some feature that would help them with their day to day work.

Whom should I please? I just want to code. Which path will lead to less dumb conflicts like this?

Comment: Off topic, but you might want to include less identifiable information in your post. You never know what your employer's monitoring these days, or what they'll take exception to.

Comment: Please whoever owns the rights to the code, I'd say. Or do you have two bosses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you are getting your first taste of the world of a manager!  I'm doing exactly the same thing 10 years later, with a much bigger budget and head count.  So it never really ends.

I love the answer about doing some time estimates for each requested addition, and then sitting down all parties and working on a negotiation that gets the greatest degree of satisfication.  I'm betting that since you are an intern, and many of the people you mention have seniority, that they will be able sort out amongst themselves who has the biggest stake and most power in the situation.  But if not, don't hesitate to act as moderator -- after all, this is *your* project.

Other things to think about:

**Types of stake holders:**

- **Customers** - the person who controls the budget is often the most powerful of stakeholders, after all, they control your ability to do the work by controlling your funding.  For an internal tool, this is probably an internal stakeholder, but it may be someone from a non-engineering group, if this tool is for a non-engineering purpose.
- **Users** - in the long run, users often make or break a tool.  They definitely determine the tool's longetivity.  It's not unusual, though, for users to lack advocates.  And in a big internal project, it's entirely possible that users are not the customers.
- **Technical Management** - particularly when you are an intern and when you are working on an internal project, technical management is the group that's most important for you (as an individual) to please.  They may have their own stake in the feature set, as they may be looking for a certain feature path for the product that fits a long term technological end game.  Ideally, they should be on your side, and helping to figure out the best feature set.

In a big company, hopefully these roles are really well defined.  Probably with an org chart.  But not necessarily.  And in a group that's used to working together, they may not make it really clear to a new comer exactly what the official roles are.  As the guy doing the work, you're job should be to accurately and honestly tell them your best guess on what effort it will take to get the feature done.  And to be open to ideas for making it cheaper/easier.

**Negotiation**:

The best negotiation advice I've ever gotten was "A good negotiation is one where everyone thinks they won".  Sadly, the frequent outcome is that everyone feels equally screwed.  The trick between every stakeholder leaving happy and every stakeholder feeling beaten down is to see the big picture and be innovative about getting everyone's needs met.  In the end, no one really cares *how* you do it, if you can make their jobs easier, they will be happy.  So finding features that serves everyone well can be the key to resolving the conflict.

Being able to do this well will *really* make a positive impact on your bosses.  This is an extremely rare skill, and this type of finesse does get noticed.

Not having it does not mark you as a pariah, however, not many engineers enjoy negotiation.  And it's never worth making every engineer be good at it.  It's far better to find an engineering manager who is good at negotiating and to let them be the "speaker for the geeks", so the rest of the engineers can do their work in peace. :)

Answer (score 1):

Sit the two parties down in the same room. Show them a list of the features each has asked for and how long you think each will take. Then explain that all of it is possible but all of it takes time, and ask them to come to agreement on what they would like when. Note down what is agreed and mail it to everyone afterwards so there is a record. Don't forget to pad your estimates to allow for testing and debugging time.

Alternatively, work out who the person directly responsible for managing you is, implement what they tell you (feeding back estimates of how long each thing will take) and tell anyone else who asks you to implement anything to go talk to that person to get it on your schedule; then doing the above management work becomes their problem.

Explain, if doing one of the above does not cause the matter does not resolve itself, that the Californians' features would require a refactor, and if you are going to do that you would rather hold off implementing any features for the other party until that is complete since doing the same work twice is wasteful.